# pickerInput from Shiny doesn't work properly when you make changes in your dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, pickerinput

I am creating an app where you can select the columns that you want to see/show and do the logarithm or sqrt to the entire dataframe. The first option (selection) is running through `pickerInput` and the second with `checkboxInput`s.

In order to show the table with your selection or your changes in the dataframe, you have to click an `actionButton`. The selection of the columns works perfectly but if you click one of the `checkboxInput` after your selection, the selection is removed and you will see all the columns again.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

This is how it looks when you want to do the logarithm after your selection. The selection of the columns disappear.

[image: image 3]

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
     
      uiOutput("picker"),
      
      checkboxInput("play", strong("I want to play with my data"), value = FALSE),
      
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.play == 1",
        checkboxInput("change_log2", "Log2 transformation", value = FALSE),
        checkboxInput("run_sqrt", "sqrt option", value = FALSE)),
    
    
      actionButton("view", "View Selection")
      
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      h2('Mydata'),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
    )
  )
)

library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })
  
  data1 <- reactive({
    
    dat <- data()
    
    if(input$change_log2){
      dat <- log2(dat)
    }
    
    if(input$run_sqrt){
      dat <- sqrt(dat)
    }
    
    dat
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$play, {
    
    if(!input$play) {
      updateCheckboxInput(session, "change_log2", value = FALSE)
      updateCheckboxInput(session, "run_sqrt", value = FALSE)
    }
    
  })
  
  
  output$picker <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'pick', 
                label = 'Choose', 
                choices = colnames(data1()),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = T,
                selected = colnames(data1())
                )
  })
  
  datasetInput <- eventReactive(input$view,{
    
    datasetInput <- data1() %>% 
      select(input$pick)
    
    return(datasetInput)
    
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT({
   
      datatable(
        datasetInput(),
        filter="top", 
        rownames = FALSE,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        
        options = list(
          dom = 'Blfrtip',
          buttons =
            list('copy', 'print', list(
              extend = 'collection',
              buttons = list(
                list(extend = 'csv', filename = "File", title = NULL),
                list(extend = 'excel', filename = "File", title = NULL)),
              text = 'Download'
            ))
        ),
        class = "display"
      )
  })
}


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Does anyone know what I should do to fix this?

Thanks very much in advance

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your `pickerInput` is based on `data1()`, and that changes based on the checkbox selection.  In fact, it should be using `data()`.  Try this

```
  output$picker <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'pick', 
                label = 'Choose', 
                choices = colnames(data()),
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                multiple = T,
                selected = colnames(data())
    )
  })
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I couldn't think that it was the problem!

Comment: One question, if for example data1() has 2 extra columns (which you cannot find in data() ), how would it be? because in that case I would be interested in using data1() in the `pickerInput` but... the error appears again...

Comment: I would have to see how you are creating those two extra columns.  Then you can move that creation to data().  Perhaps you can post it as a new question with [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I posted it as a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68738147/output-from-1-pickerinput-in-shiny-automatically-updates-when-i-do-changes-in-th Thanks!